# Converting one .ts file into a number of .flac files

Tags: audio-conversion, flac

I have a 45 GB .ts file of a concert. I want to take just the audio of the file and convert it to a series of .flac tracks. I tried to use vlc to convert the audio to .flac and then cut that file into parts using Audacity but the end result was of very poor quality. What's the best way of going about this? I'm running Windows 10 on a rather low end laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert (more precisely, remux) it to mka with mkvtoolnix, add chapters with it (if the ts does not have them) and split it per chapter. Then you can convert the mka files to flac.

It doesn't make much sense to convert them to flac if the audio stream wasn't encoded losslessly, unless the audio stream (or all container format that can be used to mux it) is not supported by the playback platform btw.